# How to redirect after successful form submission using FormData() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having trouble redirecting a user after successful form upload and submission using `XMLHttpRequest()` with `FormData()` in jQuery. For now, the form is quite simple.

What I need is, if when the user has successfully uploaded a file, with text inputs, the user will then be redirected to a different page, in this case, index.php . I have tried `success: function()` and it wouldn't work. I am not getting any errors at the moment, other than the last if statement I commented out.

Please find my code below. Your help is very much appreciated!

TIA

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    audio_post.addEventListener("submit", function (e){

            e.preventDefault();

    var progress_percent = Math.round(e.loaded/e.total*100);

    request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
        document.querySelector('.progress_res').innerHTML = 'Your Upload is ' + Math.round(e.loaded/e.total*100) + '% complete.';
    }, false);

            var audio_form = new FormData();
            audio_form.append("file", audio_file.files[0]);
            audio_form.append("title", $('.lesson-title').val());
            audio_form.append("description", $('.lesson-description').val());
            audio_form.append("category", $('.lesson-category').val());
            audio_form.append("tags", $('.lesson-tags').val());

            request.open("post", DIR+"/ajax/audio_lesson_requests.php");
            request.send(audio_form);

            /* This does not help at all. Prevents the data and files being parsed.
            if (progress_percent == 100){
            window.location.href = DIR+'/index.php';
            }*/
    });
```

Comment: I'd imagine you should be calculating the `progress_percent` **inside** the progress event, not before it. That said, please provide a bit more information. What are you expecting to happen, and what *actually* happens? Do you see any errors in console? What debugging steps have you taken? Help us help you :)

Comment: I tried many variables of successfully redirecting the user to index.php after the form and files has been successfully submitted and stored. One of the methods I used is the last if statement to redirect the user should the result of the upload be completed that the page be redirected to index.php

Comment: I am not getting any errors. Except the fact the page does not redirect after successful submission or the page does not refresh itself.